# Mysql How to SELECT information based other tables

Tags: mysql

I would like to get `tokens`. E.g if i would like to `SELECT` `Gregor, Liza` and if we look into `committee` it should retrive then their own tokens and also `Matt, Bob` tokens

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO users (name)
VALUES ("Gregor"),
    ("Liza"),
    ("Matt"),
    ("Bob"),
    ("Tom");
    
CREATE TABLE committee(
    user_id INT,
    friend_id INT,
    member_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `friend_id`, `member_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`friend_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO committee (user_id, friend_id, member_id)
VALUES (1, 2, 3),
(1, 2, 4);

CREATE TABLE tokens(
    user_id INT,
    token VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO tokens (user_id, token)
VALUES (1, "lclasld2"),
    (2, "xxkakdasd"),
    (3, "123kdkfs"),
    (4, "hjj32"),
    (5, "zz3dja");
```

Current query i got:

```
SELECT token FROM tokens WHERE user_id IN (1, 2);
```

How it behave now:

```
user_id, token
1, lclasld2
2, xxkakdasd
```

What i expect, when i run the query:

```
user_id, token
1, lclasld2
2, xxkakdasd
3, 123kdkfs
4, hjj32
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's enough to use the query without where clause

```
SELECT * FROM tokens
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database design could be better or the schema values that you have used for demo arent correct.

> You can try this

```
SELECT token
FROM   tokens
WHERE  user_id IN (SELECT member_id
                   FROM   committee
                   WHERE  user_id IN ( 1, 2 ))
        OR user_id IN ( 1, 2 );
```